# Restrict courses from displaying on Moodle conditionally based on user profile field?

Tags: moodle

I have an installation of Moodle 2.8.3 and I've added a custom user field, "role", to the user profiles. I can hide activities and documents based on that user field, however, if there is an entire course that is only for one role, the other roles see it.

Example:
I'm a client and I'm looking through the course catalog. I see a course "XYZ" and click on it to enroll but the course is totally empty because it's for employees only.

Are there any examples of this being done? I've done some research and found [IOMAD](http://www.iomad.org/) but it's a completely custom deployment of Moodle and would need to go through a lengthy approval process and then be reinstalled on dev, imp, and prod.

Answer (score 0):

Totara has audience visibility, so you can restrict courses to members of an audience.
http://help.totaralms.com/Audience_Based_Visibility.htm

Totara is a distribution of Moodle, aimed at enterprises.
http://www.totaralms.com/

I think the audience visibility code would be difficult to port to Moodle though. You can try out the Totara seedlings code from this link. https://github.com/totara/seedlings

Then once installed, switch on audience visibility using the help link above